# What is the function in R to calculate p-value for KS test if I only know the D value and sample size?

Tags: r

I am doing a one sample KS test.  I have the D value and sample size.  Is there a function in R to calculate the p-value? I cannot use ks.test because I only have D value and sample size.

Answer (score 0):

The test statistic has an approximate kolmogorov distribution under the null hypothesis. Look to see whether there's an R function to compute that. If not, you can write your own. The CDF of the kolmogorv distribution is

$$ P(K\leq x)=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{x}\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-(2k-1)^2\pi^2/(8x^2)} $$

so for a given value of $D$ the approximate $p$-value is

$$ 1 - \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{D}\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-(2k-1)^2\pi^2/(8D^2)} $$

Comment: Thanks.  But where does the sample size n go in this equation?

Comment: Only the asymptotic distribution is known exactly, so the sample size doesn't enter the equation.

Comment: Your answer seems to ignore the actual relationship between $K$ and $D$. Specifically, $\sqrt{n} D_n$ asymptotically has the Kolmogorov distribution. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Kolmogorov_distribution) for example. (@Jacky -- this shows where the sample size comes in)